jest testing custom hook using useLocation
I currently encountered a case that I want to write a unit test for my custom hook, said useMyHook in which called useLocation
a simple case of the hook is sth. like this:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const useMyHook = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation()
  const { myState, setMyState } = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    switch(pathname) {
    case '/':
      setMyState('a')
      break
    case '/b':
      setMyState('b')
      break
    default:
      setMyState('c')
      break
    }
  }, [pathname])
  
  return myState
}

my test is like:
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import useMyHook from '../useMyHook'

describe('useEventId', () => {
  it('path matches roleSelection', () => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'), // since you still want to use the actual MemoryRouter
      useLocation: () => ({
        pathname: '/',
      }),
    }))
    const state = renderHook(() => useMyHook())
    expect(state).toBe('a')
  })
})

However, I kept getting this error:

useLocation() may be used only in the context of a  component.

Can anyone point out what's the proper way to test this kind of custom hook?


Don't mock react-router-dom module.

useState() hook returns an array, not an object.

You should wrap the hook with <MemoryRouter/> component


e.g.
useMyHook.ts:
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export const useMyHook = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState<string | undefined>();
  useEffect(() => {
    switch (pathname) {
      case '/':
        setMyState('a');
        break;
      case '/b':
        setMyState('b');
        break;
      default:
        setMyState('c');
        break;
    }
  }, [pathname]);

  return myState;
};

useMyHook.test.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useMyHook } from './useMyHook';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

describe('useEventId', () => {
  it('path matches default', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(), {
      wrapper: ({ children }) => <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/c']}>{children}</MemoryRouter>,
    });
    expect(result.current).toBe('c');
  });

  it('path matches /', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(), {
      wrapper: ({ children }) => <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>{children}</MemoryRouter>,
    });
    expect(result.current).toBe('a');
  });

  it('path matches /b', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(), {
      wrapper: ({ children }) => <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/b']}>{children}</MemoryRouter>,
    });
    expect(result.current).toBe('b');
  });
});

Test result:
 PASS  stackoverflow/78477167/useMyHook.test.tsx
  useEventId
    √ path matches default (12 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    √ path matches / (2 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    √ path matches /b (2 ms)                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.201 s, estimated 10 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.


you're very correct!
This is more resonable, imho

You need to wrap your test environment inside a router context ( same as you do in a real router example ), but using the MemoryRouter component.
So, you need to wrap your hook in a functional component that provides the necessary context.
const wrapper = ({ children }) => <MemoryRouter>{children}</MemoryRouter>

This is a full example of the code.
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import useMyHook from '../useMyHook';


const wrapper = ({ children }) => <MemoryRouter>{children}</MemoryRouter>;

describe('useMyHook', () => {
  it('returns "a" when pathname is "/"', () => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
      useLocation: () => ({
        pathname: '/',
      }),
    }));

    // Use the custom wrapper to provide the router context
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(), { wrapper });

    expect(result.current).toBe('a');
  });

  it('returns "b" when pathname is "/b"', () => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
      useLocation: () => ({
        pathname: '/b',
      }),
    }));

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(), { wrapper });

    expect(result.current).toBe('b');
  });

  it('returns "c" for other paths', () => {
    jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
      useLocation: () => ({
        pathname: '/unknown',
      }),
    }));

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useMyHook(), { wrapper });

    expect(result.current).toBe('c');
  });
});


Thanks for your fast answer

Unterminated regular expression.
Got this when I declared the wrapper, may have sth. to do with my setting imho


ok, I change file name ext from .ts to .tsx fix!
your answer works perfectly
